# Gather vs aligned - centered equation with one number

Tags: equations

What is the way to achieve something between `gather` and `aligned`?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
    3(a-x) = 3.5x + a - 1 \\
    3a - 3x = 3.5x + a -1 \\
    a = \frac{13}{4}x - \frac{1}{2} 
\end{gather}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        3(a-x) = 3.5x + a - 1           \\
        3a - 3x = 3.5x + a -1           \\
        a = \frac{13}{4}x - \frac{1}{2} 
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

But...
How to achieve something like this? I'd like to keep the centering.
[image]

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The `gathered` environment, used within math mode, is what you're looking for.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
3(a-x) = 3.5x + a - 1 \\
3a - 3x = 3.5x + a - 1 \\
a = \frac{13}{4}x - \frac{1}{2}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Wikibooks LaTeX has a [fairly nice list](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Other_environments) of the different kinds of equation and align environments.

Comment: This works great, but the numbering is put at the bottom if the equation is too big. Is there a way to force the number to be on the center (right)?

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé place `\kern-50pt` before `\begin{gathered}` Here I used an arbitrary/context dependent negative left shift of length 50pt. Specifically, you can use any length to suit your need. Warning: most would advise against this because the math will overlap the left margin.

Comment: You probably want to use `aligned` instead of `gathered`. Just swap the terms and add `&`s to the `=`s.