# Centering in \begin{aligned} enivronment

Tags: align

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f(h) = \pi h^3 -9\pi h^2 +90\\
f'(h) = 3\pi h^2 -18\pi h\\
h_{n+1} = h_n-\frac{f(h_n)}{f'(h_n)}\\
h_{n+1} = h_n - \frac{\pi h_n^3 -9\pi h_n^2 +90}{3\pi h_n^2 -18\pi h_n}\\
h_{n+1} = \frac{3\pi h_n^3 - 18\pi h_n^2 - \pi h_n^3 -9\pi h_n^2 +9}{3\pi h_n^2 -18\pi h_n}\\
h_{n+1} = \frac{2\pi h_n^3-9\pi h_n^2-90}{3\pi h_n^2-18\pi h}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

What do I do to center my equations in these case?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  you can use `gathered` instead of `aligned`.  that is intended to center each line independently.  you might also gain some benefit from reading the `amsmath` users guide -- `texdoc amsmath`.

Comment: looks like a duplicate of this question: [Gather vs aligned - centered equation with one number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/277234/579)