# i want to give equation number to multi-line equations

Tags: equations, amsmath

am trying to group the equations then give them 1 number as group

```
  \begin{align*}
     &  \sigma_w^2(t)=q_1(t)\sigma_1^2(t)+q_2(t)\sigma_2^2(t)\\
         & \text{where} \\
      & q_1(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{t}P(i)  \:\& \: q_1(t)=\sum_{i=t+1}^{I}P(i)
    \\
     & mu_1(t)= \sum_{i=1}^{t}\frac{iP(i)}{q_1(t)} \: \& \: \mu_2(t)= \sum_{i=t+1}^{I}\frac{iP(i)}{q_2(t)}
    \\
     & \sigma_1^2(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{t}[i-\mu_1(t)]^2 \frac{P(i)}{q_1(t)} \: \& \: \sum_{i=t+1}^{I}[i-\mu_1(t)]^2 \frac{P(i)}{q_2(t)}\\
    \label{EqOtsu}
    \end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: Does [this answer your question?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277234/gather-vs-aligned-centered-equation-with-one-number/277238)

Answer (score 1):

Your readers would have a hard time in understanding what the unique number refers to; I suggest using `subequations`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{EqOtsu}
\begin{equation}
\sigma_w^2(t)=q_1(t)\sigma_1^2(t)+q_2(t)\sigma_2^2(t) \tag{\ref{EqOtsu}}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{gather}
q_1(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{t}P(i)
\quad\&\quad
q_1(t)=\sum_{i=t+1}^{I}P(i)
\\
\mu_1(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{t}\frac{iP(i)}{q_1(t)}
\quad\&\quad
\mu_2(t)= \sum_{i=t+1}^{I}\frac{iP(i)}{q_2(t)}
\\
\sigma_1^2(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{t}[i-\mu_1(t)]^2 \frac{P(i)}{q_1(t)}
\quad\&\quad
\sigma_2^2(t)=\sum_{i=t+1}^{I}[i-\mu_1(t)]^2 \frac{P(i)}{q_2(t)}
\end{gather}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `aligned` enivoment instead of `align`. `aligned` can be used inside an `equation`.

Thus the multi line expression can be obtained with:

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
     &  \sigma_w^2(t)=q_1(t)\sigma_1^2(t)+q_2(t)\sigma_2^2(t)\\
         & \text{where} \\
      & q_1(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{t}P(i)  \:\& \: q_1(t)=\sum_{i=t+1}^{I}P(i)
    \\
     & mu_1(t)= \sum_{i=1}^{t}\frac{iP(i)}{q_1(t)} \: \& \: \mu_2(t)= \sum_{i=t+1}^{I}\frac{iP(i)}{q_2(t)}
    \\
     & \sigma_1^2(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{t}[i-\mu_1(t)]^2 \frac{P(i)}{q_1(t)} \: \& \: \sum_{i=t+1}^{I}[i-\mu_1(t)]^2 \frac{P(i)}{q_2(t)}\\
    \label{EqOtsu}
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

[image]